# Django view returning POST instead of GET request

Tags: python, django, post, get, request

So I have these working views for registration and login using POST requests, both of which returning profile.html.

The problem is the login and registration views return a POST to the login or register urls when i submit the forms(according to cmd), to run the necessary functions.
which means it is simply **rendering the profile.html, but not running ITS view function.**

How do i have the form submissions **send a GET to the profile view while still having them send POST for their own respective functions**.

**Views:**

```
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = log_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                print("user exists")
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'profile.html')
            else:
                print("user does not exist")
                print(form.errors)
                return render(request, 'login.html', {
                    'form2': log_form
                })
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html', {
            'form2': log_form
            })
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html', {
            'form2': log_form
        })


def profile(request, username): 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = Users.objects.get(username=username)
        interests = []
        interest_list = Interests.objects.filter(member=user)#i got 5 objs here
        for i in interest_list:
            interests.append(i.item)
            print('added interest')
        info = Bios.objects.get(author=user)
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {
            'user': user,
            "interests": interests,
            'info': info
        })
```

**Urls:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('reg/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('log/', views.log_in, name='login'),
    path('profile/<str:username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('feed/', views.feed, name='feed')

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**login form:**

```
<form method='POST' action="{%url 'login' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p>Username: {{form2.username}}</p>
                        <p>Password: {{form2.password}}</p>
                        {{form2.errors}}
                        <input type="submit" value="submit">
                        <p style='margin-top: 10px;'>Don't have an account?<a href="{% url 'register' %}"> Register</a></p>
                    </form>
```

**register form:**

```
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'register' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p>Username: {{form.username}}</p>
                        <p>Email:    {{form.email}}</p>
                        <p>Password: {{form.password}}</p>
                        <p>Phone:    {{form.phone}}</p>
                        <p>First name:   {{form.first_name}}</p>
                        <p>Last name:    {{form.last_name}}</p>
                        {{form.errors}}
                        {% if form.errors %}
                            {% for field in form %}
                                {% for error in field.errors %}
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                                    </p>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                                <p>
                                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
                        <p style="margin-top: 5px;">Already have an account?<a href="{% url 'login' %}"> Log In</a></p>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login page should be accessed twice: when the user is redirected to it , so using GET, and again when the user sends the filled form, this time using POST. Your view logic should deal with the two types of requisition:

```py
def user_login(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = UserForm(request.POST) # note that I renamed your form
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('profile', kwargs={username=user})
    else: # request is GET
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

@require_GET()
def profile(request, username): 
    user = Users.objects.get(username=username)
    interests = Interests.objects.filter(member=user).values_list('item', flat=True)       
    info = Bios.objects.get(author=user)
    context = {
        'user': user,
        "interests": interests,
        'info': info
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

I also changed the profile view a little bit to use what I believe to be the best practices in Django function based views.

Comment: At first I just accepted the cleaner code with the persisting issue, but i just realized I can pass in the username argument along with redirect. So i Imported it and now we're good. THANKS!